# AJAX load within an AJAX load

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I am using buttons that are being run with JS AJAX loads. Just click on them and the run a javascript function to load the contents of a php file into a div. This is necessary because I can't have a POST form reloading my page every time a button is pushed. I also have these buttons within an html section of a php file that is being AJAX loaded within the main page. I'm doing that because I need the entire page to update itself at a certain point. So to illustrate:

Main HTML page: includes JS AJAX request to get entire page (including buttons) and update it every half second ====> this entire page is being retrieved from a php file that includes the buttons. This file has more AJAX requests to let the buttons respond in real time. They get another php file every time a button is pushed =====> other php file runs the back code.

My problem is this: My site needs to be very sensitive to the user's clicking buttons, and this layering of AJAX requests is creating quite a bit of lag. Before I had all the buttons and the AJAX requests connected to them all in the main page, and then the timing was fine - no lag. But (as I explained earlier) I need the whole to reload itself constantly as to react when certain variables in the PHP back code equal something specific, so I moved all the buttons into another php file to be AJAX requested by the main page once every quarter second. Even when I request it every 100th of a second there's still a lot of lag.

Relevant main page code:

```
<script>
    function wonfunction()
    {
        $.get('wonphp.php', function(data){
        $('#won').html(data);
        });
    }
    setInterval(wonfunction, 10);
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="won"></div>
    <body>
    </html>
```

Relevant wonphp.php code (the page code including buttons):

```
    <script>
    $('#A').click(function()
    {
        $.get('clickA.php', function(data){
        $('#clickdiv').html(data);
        });
    });

    $('#B').click(function()
    {
        $.get('clickB.php', function(data){
        $('#clickdiv').html(data);
        });
    });

    $('#C').click(function()
    {
        $.get('clickC.php', function(data){
        $('#clickdiv').html(data);
        });
    });
    </script>
    <div id="clickdiv"></div>
    <p align="center"><b><font face="Helvetica" color="#000080"><a href="testrand.php">Click here to purchase more claim credits.</a></font></b></p>
    <p align="center"><img src="images/SetA.jpg" id="A" class="button">
    <img src="images/SetB.jpg" id="B" class="button">
    <img src="images/SetC.jpg" id="C" class="button">
```

OK thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Do you really need to update the *whole* page every half second? It'll be this more than anything that's causing the lag. The AJAX request might take 300-400ms, and then the browser has to render the new content, then just as the browser has finished it's asked to make another asynchronous request. If you need certain parts of a site updated, *only fetch the parts you need*, and do it a little less often than every 500ms.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to create a slot machine and I think your architecture is maybe not suitable for it and maybe the choice of technology neither. It really sounds like you want to use flash for example.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your questions. Flag for moderator attention if you need assistance with something.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should rework your code to make less requests as possible.

You could use `JSON` requests, using polling via `setInterval` if needed, building the resulting html using one of the many nice template engines for client-side javascript ([Mustache](http://git.io/GmGocg) or [jQuery.tmpl](http://git.io/TFciAw)).

```
function poller() {
    $.getJSON('/wonphp.php?kind=json', function (data) {
        // prepare the resulting data and render the result or
        // trigger an event to another function that will check
        // if initial data has changed rendering html
    });
}
setInterval(poller, 10000); // poll every 10 seconds 
poller(); // initial load
```

If you can't use `JSON`, set the intervals at a resonable number and use [jQuery.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) events triggering a [jQuery.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) since it is less error prone in a cross-browser environment (you should look at the code).

So it's something like this:

```
function load_won() {
    $('#won').load('wonphp.php');
}
setInterval(load_won, 5000);
load_won();

$('#A').live('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#clickdiv').load('clickA.php');
});
```